# Finding error in my script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, regular-expression

I have a messy script which should get the name of the site (like `https://google.com/etc`):

```
#!/bin/bash

ARTIST=$(echo "$@" | grep -oP 'https:\\/\\/\\K.+?(?=.com)' | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g")

echo $(echo "$@" | grep -oP 'https:\\/\\/\\K.+?(?=.com)' | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g")
echo "$ARTIST"

echo "$@"
```

And for some reason, `$(...)` doesn't return anything while running outside of the script works fine.

```
$ ./test.sh https://nothing.bandcamp.com/music   
https://nothing.bandcamp.com/music
```

Expected behavior:

```
$ echo "https://nothing.bandcamp.com/music" | grep -oP 'https:\\/\\/\\K.+?(?=.com)' | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g" 
Nothing.Bandcamp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please avoid using Pastebin at all costs on our site, thank you.

Comment: `echo https://nothing.bandcamp.com/music | grep -oP 'https:\\/\\/\\K.+?(?=.com)'` returns nothing, I just tested it, I'm no expert on regular expressions, so I will leave this question to others. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping `\`  itself in your `grep` regular expression.   i.e. your `\\/` means a literal backslash followed by a forward slash, and `\\K` means a literal backslash followed by a capital K.

Also, `/` doesn't even need to be escaped with `grep` - that's only necessary when using `/` as a regex delimiter, as is the default with `sed` or `perl` (and, usually, it's better to just use another delimiter - like `,` or `:`, or `=`).

Use just plain un-escaped `/`, and `\K` instead.  For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
ARTIST=$(echo "$@" | grep -oP 'https://\K.+?(?=.com)' | sed -e 's/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g')
echo "$ARTIST"
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./test.sh https://nothing.bandcamp.com/music   
Nothing.Bandcamp

$ echo "https://nothing.bandcamp.com/music" | grep -oP 'https://\K.+?(?=.com)' | sed -e 's/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g'
Nothing.Bandcamp
```

Note: this is as true when run on the command line as it is when run in a script.

e.g. the following produces **no output**, same as it would in a script:

```
$ echo "https://nothing.bandcamp.com/music" | grep -oP 'https:\\/\\/\\K.+?(?=.com)' | sed -e "s/\b\(.\)/\u\1/g"
```

Comment: Welp, I'm using Fish Shell and it actually returns "Nothing.Bandcamp" while in bash it isn't. So, Fish was causing trouble.